# Errors uploading plugin to QGIS python plugin repository

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, plugins

I'm trying to upload my first plugin to: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/add/

I keep getting the following error:

> There were errors reading plugin package (please check also your plugin's metadata). Package name must start with an ASCII letter and can contain ASCII letters, digits and the signs '-' and '_'.

My package name is "DEMTools" and I've checked the plugin's metadata file, but everything looks to be in order. This error message doesn't give me a lot to go on and I've never uploaded a plugin before. Are there some common issues I should look for or is there some detailed guide to preparing a plugin package for **upload**? (I don't need help with creating the plugin just uploading it to the Plugin Repository. I used Plugin Builder to create the plugin and it runs fine on my local machine.)

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also submitted this as a bug report and it was answered [here](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10324)

For ease of zipping, I had thrown only the files I needed into another folder named 'Qgis Repo' and just renamed the zip file to 'DEMTools'. This obviously didn't change the name of the top level directory and so the upload verification didn't like that it wasn't matching the name of the plugin.